# Правильный стиль разметки

Tags: html

Как лучше писать списки

1)В строчку

```
<ul id="linkers"><li><a href="football.html">Футбол</a></li><li><a href="baseball.html">Бейсбол</a></li></ul>
```

2)или

```
    <ul id="linkers">
            <li>
                <a href="football.html">Футбол</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="baseball.html">Бейсбол</a>
            </li>
     </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

конечно 2 - так лучше код читать

Answer (score 1):

Если сравнивать с 1, то, естественно, лучше 2. Но вообще, я бы писал примерно так:

```
<ul id="linkers">
 <li><a href="football.html">Футбол</a></li>
 <li><a href="baseball.html">Бейсбол</a></li>
</ul>
```

***Это просто моё предпочтение.***